# Fan control in HP folio 13 with coolsense for windows installed

Tags: laptop, temperature

I have a HP laptop which has the coolsense software installed.
I haven't found information about if elementary OS has this type of software or similar to avoid high temperature in the machine.
Anyone could solve my doubt, please?

Thanks for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the `tlp` or `thermald` softwares, or both.

TLP is an advanced power management tool for Linux. It comes with a
 default configuration already optimized for battery life. At the same
 time it is highly customizable to fulfil specific user requirements.

```
sudo apt install tlp
```

Thermal Daemon is a Linux daemon for monitoring and
 controlling platform temperatures. Once the system
 temperature reaches a certain threshold, the Linux daemon
 activates various cooling methods to try to cool the system.

```
sudo apt install thermald
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to install those in my laptop and I will write the feedback.

Comment: Hello, with these softwares installed with default configuration my laptop gets very high temperature after 1 hour working. The temperature is very very high in the CPU area.

However working in windows 10 the laptop hasn't any problem about this issue.

Any ideas about what could happend?
Regards